# subset only possible combinations from an R data.frame

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, subset

Function `foo` forces the `subset` to always include all values of `time` in any subsetting.

For example, if I only want to subset `prof == 1` from `dat`, `foo` also adds `time==1; time==2; time==3; time==4` to that subsetting.

But sometime adding some values of `time` (in this example `time==1` and `time==4`) causes `subset` to throw in an error because there is no data for such subsettings.

I was wondering how I could filter out such errors in my output i.e., only get the output for possible subettings (here `time == 2 and 3`)?

***Note:*** data is toy, a functional solution is appreciated.

```
# data.frame:
dat <- data.frame(time = c(1,3,2,4), prof = c(2,1,1,2)) 

# Function:
foo <- function(data, mod){

     tim <- sort(unique(data$time))

        s <- substitute(mod)
        G <- lapply(tim, function(x) bquote(.(s) & time == .(x)))

       lapply(1:length(G), function(i) subset(data, G[[i]]))
}
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(dat, prof == 1) # Error in subset(data, G[[i]]) : 'subset' must be logical

# DESIRED OUTPUT:
 [[1]]
   time prof
 1    2    1

[[2]]
  time prof
1    3    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is `'subset' must be logical`, which means `subset` doesn't know what to do with the `call` objects produced by `bquote`. Putting `G[[i]]` in `eval` should get things working:

```r
dat <- data.frame(time = c(1,3,2,4), prof = c(2,1,1,2)) 
data <- dat; mod <- substitute(prof == 1)

foo <- function(data, mod){

    tim <- sort(unique(data$time))

    s <- substitute(mod)
    G <- lapply(tim, function(x) bquote(.(s) & time == .(x)))

    lapply(1:length(G), function(i) subset(data, eval(G[[i]]))) # <- Use `eval`
}

foo(dat, prof == 1)
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
[1] time prof
<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)

[[2]]
  time prof
3    2    1

[[3]]
  time prof
2    3    1

[[4]]
[1] time prof
<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)
```

The `<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)` just says that there are 0 rows. Just subset the output list to get the data frames you need.

I should also point out that your function basically does the same thing as `dat[dat$prof == 1,]` since you are comparing `prof` for every value of `time` (it returns a data frame rather than a list, but that's a fairly minor detal). I'm not sure what you have planned, but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: You could add one more line to the function: `res <- lapply(.); return(res[lapply(res, nrow) > 0])`.

Comment: @jay.sf it would be even easier to forgo the function completely and just do `dat[dat$prof == 1,]`. But I think the OP might have something planned that isn't immediately obvious, which is why I just pointed out the error in his function rather than improving it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant with this addition we would achieve OPs desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Subset the dataframe, split it up on time elements:

```
    subset_df <- function(df, prof_no){


      split(df[df$prof == prof_no,], df[df$prof == prof_no, "time"]) 


}
```

Application:

```
subset_df(dat, 1)
```

Data Used:

```
dat <- data.frame(time = c(1,3,2,4), prof = c(2,1,1,2))
```